# Graphviz bold font attribute

Tags: graphviz

I would like to change font attribute as the example below

[image: example]

Is there any way to change the font of just few words inside a `label` instead of using the global attribute change `fontname="times bold italic"` ? I need to convert to png.

Answer (score 38):

You may use [HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) in graphviz and define labels with partially bold text:

```
mynode [label=<<FONT FACE="boldfontname">bold text</FONT>>]
```

Or use the `<B>` tag:

```
mynode [label=< <B>bold text</B> regular text >]
```

Comment: Note the restriction ... "In addition, all of these markups are currently **only available via the cairo and svg** renderers."

Comment: @cmcginty The OP wanted to convert to png, cairo should work perfectly fine for this - a downvote seems a bit harsh ...

Comment: @marapet I tried to remove the downvote when I figured out why it wasn't working for me, but the time had expired. If you edit the answer then SO will let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really desperate, you could also copy&paste **bold unicode strings** into your graph description, for example using the following website:

https://lingojam.com/BoldTextGenerator

Apparently, this too does not work in all setups.

Comment: Unfortunately the characters do not render (square boxes with some code are shown). What was your setup to get this (last resort) solution working?

Comment: Frankly, I do not remember anymore. I guess it was just another option to try, but witout guarantees.