# How can I make my node text bold using attributes of the nodes when trying to draw graph structure using pydot and graphviz?

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I have created a node using `pydot` and GraphViz as follows:

```py
import pydot
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type = 'digraph')

a = pydot.Node("First Node", style = "filled", color = "red")
graph.add_node(a)
```

I want text of node `a` to be bold.  How can I do it?  Is there any attribute of the node like style, color?
Thank you.

Edit:  If I need to add \n in the middle of the text, can I simply put \n in the middle as shown:

```
<<font face="boldfontname">First\nNode</font>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphviz bold font attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194104/graphviz-bold-font-attribute)

Comment: If I need to use breaking the line function, then, shall I do? <<font face = "boldfontname">>First\nNode</font>>?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30200953/1959808)) is to use HTML:

```
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
nd = pydot.Node(
    'First Node',
    label='<<font face="boldfontname">First Node</font>>',
    style='filled',
    color='red')
graph.add_node(nd)
graph.write_pdf('foo.pdf')
```

Defining a [`fontname`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fontname) appears to be another possibility.

Comment: If I need to use breaking the line function, then, shall I do?
<<font face = "boldfontname">>First\nNode</font>>?